# trying to use data detail in buttons but getting a unexpected error

Tags: javascript

I am using the following code which displays my items from a database on the screen. I have tried adding a button to each of them using data detail as this is how i am passing data through local storage. However when i run this code i get an error message with an `unexpected {` in the `html +=` line, can you not do this?

```
function display(results) {
    article = document.getElementById("homeArticle");
    var html = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){ 
        var item = results[i];

        var name = item.P_NAME;
        var description = item.P_DESCRIPTION;
        var price = item.P_PRICE;
        var quant = item.P_QUANTITY;
            // next I add to the string that we want to place on the page
        html += '<section id="homePageSection"><div id="test"> <p>Name: ' + name + '</p><p>Description: ' + description + '</p><p>Price: £' + price + '</p><p>Quantity: ' + quant + '</p><button data-detail='{"name":"banana", "cost": "19"}'>Bananas</button></div></section>';   
    };
    article.innerHTML = html;
}


function getItems() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function() {
        var results = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        display(results.rows);
    };
    xhr.open("GET", "displayData.php");
    xhr.send();
}

window.addEventListener("load", getItems);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to escape the single quotes inside your string:

```
'</p><button data-detail=\'{"name":"banana", "cost": "19"}\'>Bananas</button></div></section>'
```

Comment: okay thats great, can i use the variables in there, so instead of banana can i have the variable name?

Comment: to add variables, you'll need to break the string: `'<button data-detail=\'{"name":' + detail_name + ', "cost":' + detail_cost + '}\'>Bananas</button>'`

Comment: when i do that, the `</div></section>' ` fall outside the string?

Comment: put them back inside the string, the important part is that you break the string for every variable you want to insert, just as you've done it with `name`, `description` etc. above

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the the ' around your stringed object using backslash.

Like this

```
'<button data-detail=\'{"name":"banana", "cost": "19"}\'>Bananas</button>'
```

Comment: this worked but when i click the button it dose not add the data detail or store it to the local storage like it should. Why could this be?

Comment: That's different question entirely, and unfortunately we don't have enough of your code to answer that.

Comment: oh okay, do you have any pointers as to where i should start to look for this problem? as for example if i just went onto my index page and put `<button data-detail='{"name":"banana", "cost": "19"}'>Bananas</button>` and click on it, it stores the detail in the local storage, but these buttons don't so would you have any idea of where to look?

Comment: The attribute `data-detail` is by default nothing in js/html. Meaning that the behavior you described with storing the contents of this attribute is probably done by a function listening to the event triggered by the buttons. This can be directly in your code, or be the works of a framework you are running. Hard to say from my point of view.